# set the CLASSPATH

Tags: java, macos, jpeg2000

I am using Mac os Sierra 10.12.3 ,I want to  execute  the byte code  on  the Java(TM) Virtual Machine
(JVM) I need to set the CLASSPATH,
 Using my terminal

```
CLASSPATH=</Users/.../Documents/jj2000/jj2000-4.1\ 3>/jj2000-4.1.jar:$CLASSPATH export CLASSPATH
```

show me

```
-bash: /jj2000-4.1.jar:: Permission denied
```

I am confusing with command line  how can I set the CLASSPATH.
My java  is

```
java version "1.8.0_20-ea"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-ea-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b20, mixed mode)
```

Please help.

Comment: Are you using literal `<` and `>` characters? Because that is how you redirect standard io - so the shell thinks you're trying to write the results to your jar file.

Answer (score 3):

Don't, ever, set a global CLASSPATH environment variable. Pass the classpath to each java program you launch: each one has its own, specific classpath.

```
java -cp /path/to/jj2000-4.1.jar:your-application.jar com.yourcompany.youapp.Main
```

Comment: sure thank you , I'd follow this documentation to install (http://www.dclunie.com/jj2000/README-5.1.html) That's why I am trying to set the class path like that.